# Can libraries with implementation seperated from decalration benefit from RVO/NRVO?

Tags: c++, c++14, static-libraries, rvo, nrvo

Just as shown in the title, I was writing a static library with a class template and several non-template operator overloads. The class template is defined in a.h, and the functions was defined in a.cc.

So I decide to go on to ask whether RVO/NRVO can benefit the user code of the library?

Edit:
I'm sorry about that, it was another question that I just asked and shouldn't be put into this question.
To make the scenior more clear, I was actually was trying to encapsulate types like uint8_t and so on, and planed to write some large interger type myself.

Comment: What has separation of declaration and definition to do with RVO/NRVO?? That's a completely different context as with `constexpr` which needs to be visible at compile time (not linker phase).

Comment: I am wondering whether or not RVO/NRVO can still happen when the definition is seperated from declaration.

Comment: Sure, why not??

Comment: Oh, then how can that happen? How do the compiler managed to do that?

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/771/Return-Value-Optimization-techniques-implemented-by-C-compilers.html) helps for understanding. It's implemented in the definition of the code in question, not with the calling code. Looks like the regular [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) also gives some information regarding that doubt.

Comment: I have just read the material you gave and I understood how it was implemented by the compiler. But what is interesting is that how compiler recognize the function compiled which has RVO/NRVO optimization since the declaration in a.h is not identical with it(the optimized version).

Comment: Are you asking how optimizers implement RVO/NRVO cross translation units?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I was asking.

Comment: [Edit] your question to clarify your intent, it is obvious people misunderstood

Comment: It is done @Passer By

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function returns a prvalue, that means (pre-C++17) that the return value is a temporary object. So, two things happen to this temporary object:

1. It has to be initialized by the function that created it.
2. It has to be used in some way by the function that called the creator (even if it is just discarded, that's still technically using it).

By the standard, if you do `return Type(...);`, the return expression is evaluated, resulting in a temporary, and that temporary is used to copy-initialize the return value object.

However, the standard says that this copy initialization doesn't have to happen if `Type` is the same type as the return prvalue object. In that case, compiler will simply apply the initialization of the temporary to the return value object directly.

By the standard, if you do `Type var = some_func(...)`, and `some_func` returns a value, then the temporary returned by `some_func` will be used to copy-initialize `var`.

However, the standard says that the copy-initialization doesn't have to happen if `Type` is the type of value that `some_func` returns. Thus, the return value object initialized by `some_func` *is `var` itself*. Not some temporary object that initializes `var`; `some_func` initializes `var` directly.

Both of these processes are wholly independent of each other.

The elision of the initialization of the return value is based on the implementation of the function. That implementation *does not care* what the caller is doing. It simply initializes the return value object directly rather than doing a copy from the return expression.

The elision of the initialization of a variable from the return value of a function *does not care* about the implementation of the function. It is based solely on the fact that the function returns a prvalue, and that the type of that prvalue is the same as the type of the object being initialized by it. It only needs to see the function's declaration to do its part of eliding the operation.

When both of these happen, you have complete elision of all copies from within the function to its eventual destination. But neither requires the other to exist.

So, consider the following:

```
Type foo()
{
  Type t;
  return t;
}

T t2 = foo();
```

By the standard, this is two copy initializations. First, the return value of `foo` is initalized by moving from `t`. Second, `t2` is initialized by moving from the return value of `foo`.

If the compiler can elide both of these, then you get 0 moves. If the compiler can elide the initialization of `t2` but not perform NRVO on `t`, then you get 1 move`. If it can't do either, then you get 2 moves (and you should immediately stop using that compiler;) ).

---

If you want more of the implementation details, then it has to do with function calling conventions and the ABI.

The storage for a function's arguments *and* return value are allocated by the caller. So, the caller sees that the function will return a prvalue, so it allocates enough storage of the appropriate alignment to store that value, then calls the function with a pointer to that storage. The function's implementation will use that storage when it is initializing the return value.

Elision, on the side of the function implementation, is merely constructing the object directly in the return value memory. Elision, on the side of the function using the return value, is simply passing in the storage for the object it will be used with. The `t2` example above will perform elision by passing the storage for `t2` as the return value storage given to `foo`.

The compiler of `foo` does not need to know or care if the return value storage is a named value or a temporary. All it knows is that it has been given storage that the return value will be constructed in.

And the compiler of the caller of `foo` only needs the function signature, since that tells it everything it needs to know to be able to perform this kind of elision.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu Is this what you are looking for? Or is it _how_ such things are implemented, as in how does the compiler/linker know where to put the values?

Comment: Thankyou for answering my question, but I still have some questions.
What you mean is that, the caller simply gives the callee an address of the return_val(if  it is the same type as the type returned by the function) and whether the function performs RVO/NRVO has nothing to do with the caller, just with the callee?

Comment: @JiaHaoXu: I meant exactly what I wrote. The caller passes it the storage for the callee to initialize. It's that simple. How the callee initializes it is the callee's business.

Comment: @Passer By Yes, I'm curious about how the compiler does it.